# A-frame a-video component Black screen errorWebGL: INVALID_VALUE: tex(Sub)Image2D: video visible size is empty

Tags: javascript, html, aframe

So i was trying a test using a-frame the goal is very simple show a video in a marker but i am runing some problems (new programmer btw), i am using just the a-video component inside a hiro marker preset as the code below:

```
<html lang="Pt-br">
  <head>
    <title>Hello!</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.9.2/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/1.6.0/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js"></script>     
  </head>  
  <body>
    <a-scene embedded arjs='sourceType: webcam; debugUIEnabled: false; detectionMode: mono_and_matrix; matrixCodeType: 3x3;'>
      <a-marker preset="hiro">
          <a-video rotation="90 0 0"autoplay="false" loop="true" src="src/video-test2.mp4"></a-video>
      </a-marker>      
        <a-entity camera></entity>      
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

my problem is that almost every time i run the index page the video won't show up, only a black square in top of the marker the error that run on console is that:

> "WebGL: INVALID_VALUE: tex (Sub) Image2D: video visible size is empty"

but some times the video work just fine no error, but it starts automatic even with `autoplay = "false"`, i am using webhost000 just for testing, maybe that is the reason.

```
A-Frame Version: 0.9.2
Platform / Device: Desktop


#1 Edit: Add a glitch link to reproduce the code. 
#2 Edit: found a solution at github a-frame issues topic using a click.
```

Reproducible Code Snippet or URL: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/join/41df347c-e26f-44c9-a3cb-9ee52724f42d (*working now! :)* )

Github issue link: https://github.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/issues/285;

Comment: A link to reproduce will help people to help you. Glitch is a good option: https://glitch.com/~aframe